# Trying to understand how to properly implement this equation to a healpix map

Tags: astrophysics, cosmology, mathematics, quasars

So i am working on reproducing a paper [(Secrest, N. J., von Hausegger, S., Rameez, M., Mohayaee, R., Sarkar, S., & Colin, J. (2021). A test of the cosmological principle with quasars. The Astrophysical Journal Letters, 908(2), L51.)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.14826)  and I have this equation
$$\sum_p\left[n_p - \left(A_0 + \sum_{j=1}^3 A_{1,j}d_{j,p}\right)\right]^2$$

the paper describes the process of how they implemented it. However I cant grasp my head around it. I have done all the previous steps but this is where I am stuck.
I have the number densities but I can't seem to figure out how to get the other variables namely, $A_0$ and the $A_{1j}$ and $d_j$.

Can someone here help me with this?

Comment: I'm not sure.. what exactly is the question? Right after the equation the paper explains what the symbols indicate. So you ask how to calculate a mean density i.e., $A_0$? You might want to explain a bit more in detail your thought processes and current status of your progess in your endeavour as it might explain the exact issue better

Comment: @planetmaker I want to know where would I get the values for A0, A1j and dj.

Comment: @planetmakeri I want to know what equations or methodology they used to reach their answers